# 1d array of length n into 2d array sqrt(n)*sqrt(n)?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

Is there any simple way to rearrange 1d array of length `n` into a `sqrt(n)` by `sqrt(n)` matrix (assuming array is always perfect square long.

I tried to make it using `for` loops but it ended in harm. `:D`

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], matrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, with numpy.

```
array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
box = int(np.sqrt(array.shape[0]))
matrix = array.reshape((box,box))
>>>
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that without the need for third party libraries

first we do the square root and we take away the decimals.

Then we select the numbers three at a time for that we use the following notation `array[0: 3]` (Return `[1, 2, 3]`)

Finally all this is stored in array_out or matrix

```
import math  
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

num=int(math.sqrt(len(array)))
array_out=[array[i*num:i*num+num] for i in range(num)]
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it natively:

```
import math

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
sq = int(math.sqrt(len(arr)))
matrix = [arr[i * sq:i * sq + sq] for i in range(sq)]

print(matrix)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```